# Sorting large arrays does not return output

Tags: java, eclipse, sorting, insertion-sort

I have been playing around with different sorting functions and the basic code. However, when I tried to increase the size of the array to over 1,000, instead of a nice output I get just blank console, and it says that the program was terminated.

Can anyone explain what might be the issue?

```
public class Sorting {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] array = generateRandomArray(10000);
        printArray(array);
        insertionSort(array);
        printArray(array);
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] arr)
    {
        System.out.print("[ ");
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[i] +" ");
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }

    public static int[] generateRandomArray(int n)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            arr[i]=rnd.nextInt(5000);
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static void insertionSort(int[] arr)
    {
        int temp, index;
        for (int i=1; i<arr.length; i++)
        {
            temp=arr[i];
            index=i-1;
            while (index>=0 && temp<arr[index])
            {
                arr[index+1]=arr[index];
                index--;
            }
            arr[index+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It does have an output for me.

Comment: I too received the output on the console of eclipse. In case you are using an IDE check for the limit on console buffer, for example for eclipse it can be set via preferences -> Run/Debug -> console

Answer (score 4):

In most IDEs e.g. Eclipse console output is limited. If you redirect output to file in Run Configuration (assuming you are using Eclipse) you should see the output.

Also enabling "Word wrap" in the console output might make it visible, again assuming it is Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks, an IDE problem indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran it on my machine. Worked fine. Make sure you import `java.util.Random`.

Comment: Every programmer argument

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is some line length limitation in Eclipse console. When I run your code in command line, it prints well.

If you want to fix this problem in eclipse, change the settings:

(1)Click 'window' menu -> 'preferences'
(2)'Run/Debug' -> 'Console'
(3)Check 'Fixed width console'

This should make your code works in Eclipse.

[image]